# How to allow Zoom-Out until an image fills a Webview and doesn't exceeed its boundaries?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-image

I'm using a common approach to display an image in Full-screen and support zooming by a  WebView and enablling zoom controls in it, my problem is when the Image width is larger than the Screen width
e.g. on Galaxy S2 screen (480px width) if I display a 600px by 600px image in a web view,  the max Zoom-out still crops the image and displays a horizontal scroll, and there's no way to zoom-out (i.e. less than 100%).

Is there a solution for this to enable the zoom to go to levels such as 50% or if there's a better approach than using the WebView and still support zoom ?

Answer (score 0):

for stretching/resizing the image to fit device screen (width) you have to load an HTML code in your `webview` which includes a `<img>` tag and we will set its width to 100%. and load that code in webview using `loadDataWithBaseURL()` method

try this

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><img style=\"border-style:dotted;border-width:5px;border-color:black;\" src= "www.myUrl.com/blahbla.jpg" alt=\"page Not Found\"></body></html>","text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

Comment: by using this method you will not be able to zoom the webview. this will just fit your image to device screen, no matter its your small hand set or a Tablet

Comment: You will not be able to zoom in and enlarge the image cause every time you zoom in/out it'll fill the screen it'll always be 100% width